# git commit deleted whole directory

Tags: git, tortoisegit

After a user committed a single file change to git, a bunch of directories that they didn't touch got deleted.  How?

Here are the last 2 commits

```
git log -10
3dc0de9 - change
ddc0fe6 - change
...
```

The top commit `3dc0de9` is the one that deleted the directories, but it only changes one file

```
git show --name-only  3dc0de9
(1 file updated)
```

and yet, 31 additional files got deleted, including 7 whole subdirectories!

```
git diff --name-only ddc0fe6..3dc0de9
(31 files deleted)
```

If I `git cherry-pick 3dc0de9`, I get only the single-file change that I expected, but I'd really like to know how this happened and how to avoid unexpected deletions

Odd... this diff shows the right thing

```
git diff --name-only 3dc0de9~1..3dc0de9
(1 file updated)
```

Answer (score 2):

`git log` (with or without `--graph`) has to present commits one at a time, so it must linearize the graph.  In so doing, it *sorts* the commits.  The default sort order is by commit timestamp—but there's a bit of subtlety here that I found confusing at first (it's not, I think, properly documented): **By default, you will see commits in their commit order, not their time-stamp order, except once you reach merges.**  In your case the merge was right at the top, which led to the confusing bit.  **Using `--graph` helps,** for several reasons.

Aside: "commit order" above refers to the way Git links the commits.  Each new commit you add remembers its parent, so that in a new repository with just three commits, they look a bit like this:

```
A <-B <-C   <--master
```

We say that the branch name `master` *points to* commit `C` because at the moment, it contains the hash ID of `C`.  Commit `C` points to commit `B` in the same way—`B` is `C`'s *parent*—and commit `B` points to commit `A`.  Because `A` was the very first commit, it points nowhere at all: it is a *root commit*.  It has no parent!  So "commit order" is `C` then `B` then `A`.  To add a new commit `D` to `master`, Git writes out commit `D` with `C` as `D`'s parent, then *changes the name `master`* so that it now points to `D`:

```
A <-B <-C <-D   <--master
```

There's nothing to sort here: Git just starts at `D`, uses its backwards pointer to find `C`, and so on.

Note that each commit, once made, is entirely read-only: the parent link in a commit is frozen in time, just like everything else about the commit.  Only the *branch name*, in this case `master`, actually changes!  New commits show up as you add them; they point back to existing commits, which haven't changed; and your branch name always points to the *last* commit in the chain.  So Git must work *backwards*, starting from the last and working towards the first.

This is easy when you have no branches and merges.  It's harder when there is a merge:

```
...--E--G--...---M--N   <-- master
      \         /
       F--...--L   <-- feature
```

Git can start at `N` and work back to `M`, but `M` has *two* parents instead of one.  Now Git has to show *one* of the two parents *first*.

#### How the sorting works

Here's the tricky bit about sorting: Git actually emits commits from a priority queue.  It's this priority queue that achieves the sorting.  The initial contents of the priority queue are all the commits explicitly named on the command line:

```
git log --option --another abcd123 --more f0bc3a1 --etc HEAD
```

names three starting points: `abcd123`, `f0bc3a1`, and `HEAD` (whatever commit hash ID that resolves to—presumably not one of the other two, otherwise there are just two starting points).

If you omit all the starting points, `git log` inserts `HEAD`, which by definition names one single commit.  For instance, if `HEAD` is attached to `master` and `master` points to commit `N`, `git log` will start at `N`.

Since the priority queue has priorities, the first element to come *out* of the queue determines which commit is shown first.  The default is to insert these commits in their commit timestamp order.  Using the various sorting options changes the order in which commits are inserted into the queue.

Actually *showing* a commit inserts, into the queue, all of that commit's parents.  So when `git log` shows a merge, that inserts all of the merge's parent commits into the queue, in their priority order.

Since the default `git log` starts with just one commit in the queue, it starts by showing `HEAD` first.  As long as that's not a merge, it has just one parent, so the queue stays at length 1 with just the (single) parent of `HEAD` in it.  This kind of `git log` shows each commit one at a time, *regardless of the commit time-stamps*.  It's only when we reach a merge commit, like your `00d4f68`, that we hit a snag.

At `00d4f68`, Git inserted both parents into the queue: `ddc0fe6` and `3dc0de9`.  This meant it now had a *choice* of which commit to show next—and by default, it sorts by commit timestamp.  The commit timestamps are set by whoever makes the commit.  If different people make different commits on different machines, and one of the machines has its time set incorrectly, you'll get some weird time-stamps, and hence some weird sortings.

#### Use `--graph`

With `--graph`, `git log` also shows the graph (as somewhat-crude ASCII art).  This has the side effect of forcing a topological sort: show all children of some parent before showing that particular parent commit.  The default is `--topo-order` but `--date-order` and `--author-date-order` are also topological sorts, and should be allowed here.  (The documentation mentions that `--date-order` *is* allowed, but both *should be*.)

Note that you can use `--topo-order` yourself (without `--graph`) to get the same topological sorting.  But without `--graph`, you can't tell when one chain of commits stops and another starts, i.e., where the two legs of the merge go, nor where they come back together.

To make the graph easier to follow, use `--oneline`.  To see which commits have which branch and tag labels as well, add `--decorate` or set `log.decorate`.

The combination of `--decorate --oneline --graph` is quite useful, and easy to remember because it spells "DOG". :-)

You can also add `--all` to start from all references (all branches and tags, plus the stash if there is one, plus any other commit references), which spells "A DOG".

Comment: Thanks for the mind bending details!  Still, I can't understand why the topmost commit `3dc0de9` would result in deleting files it didn't touch

Comment: @noelbk: it doesn't. Your `git diff ddc0fe6..3dc0de9` is comparing commit `ddc0fe6` (as the "before") with commit `3dc0de9` (as the "after"), and giving you instructions on how to change the snapshot in `ddc0fe6` into the one in `3dc0de9`. To do that, you'll *delete* everything that was *added* during the right-hand leg of the development split, that got merged-in at `00d4f68`. It doesn't matter that `ddc0fe6` isn't directly related to `3dc0de9`: `git diff` is just diffing that particular *pair* of commits.

Comment: @torek: If you write about "commit order and time-stamp order": What exacly is commit order? Is there anything else than the commits' time-stamp order?

Comment: @Christoph: I meant—and I don't think it's quite clear without a drawing—that you get the commits in the right-to-left order of `A--B--C--D--...--Z` where `Y` is `Z`'s parent, `X` is `Y`'s parent, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Aha!  It looks like a merge from a really old branch somehow reset those files.  the offending commit, `38bbeb1` is from a much older branch, but gets put on top of git log.

```
git log --graph 3dc0de9~3..master
*   00d4f68 - (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Merge branch 'master'
|\  
| * ddc0fe6 - change
| * ...snipped out 51 commits on this branch...
| * db0e306 - change
* | 3dc0de9 - change
|/  
* 38bbeb1 - change
* 5b103f6 - change
```

Now the real question is how to avoid this in the future.  I usually do git fetch and rebase, but I'm not sure what the procedure for that is in TortoiseGit

I made things "right" by resetting back to the last good commit then cherry-picking the "bad" ones:

```
git reset --hard ddc0fe6
git cherry-pick 3dc0de9
```

That got all the right changes without deleting files.

Comment: Did the branch do a revert?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I don't think there was a revert in there, but I didn't get a chance to see the warnings at the time the commit was made.  I made things "right" by resetting to the last good commit then cherry-picking the  troublesome commit